# PostgreSQL - conditionally exclude statement from WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using `PL/pgSQL` (*PostgreSQL version 10*) and wonder if there's a way to exclude statement from `WHERE` clause.

My code:

```
WHERE 
(
    e.priority >= priority_from AND
    e.priority <= priority_to
) AND
v.id = vocabulary_id_ AND
e.text LIKE '%' || search_phrase || '%'
;
```

If the parameter `vocabulary_id_` has value of `0` or `null` - the query returns 0 records because there's no such `vocabulary` with `Id` that equals `0` or `null`.

If I go with `IF ELSE` statement - I'll end up having 2 almost identical queries - one with `v.id = vocabulary_id_ AND` part, and the other without it.

Is there an easy way to exclude this part using `PL/pgSQL` syntax?

Comment: What's your expect result if `vocabulary_id_ is null`  or `vocabulary_id_=0`?

Comment: @D-Shih I'm passing the value from .NET Core project - currently `0` is being passed.

Comment: You're trying to push a business process requirement directly into the database... That's a big issue. You should review what you're trying to do because, to me, it's like you're trying to say "hey, if I don't have the email address, do this but if I do, do the same thing but with that : all with the same query".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
WHERE 
(
e.priority >= priority_from AND
e.priority <= priority_to
) And    (V.id = vocabulary_id_ or vocabulary_id_ is null or vocabulary_id_ = 0) and
e.text LIKE '%' || search_phrase || '%'
 ;
```

Just to add, at least with SQL Server, while this is convenient, at least with SQL Server, these types of queries sometimes lead to suboptimal performance.  I don't know if that is the case with postgres.

Comment: thank you very much for you answer! and good point - I haven't thought of that :)

Comment: This does not really work because you want to exclude the condition on vocabulary_id_ for 0 or NULL. This will give you wrong rows.